# How to share image on facebook in android using facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, image, post, share

I am trying to post a picture to my wall on Facebook. I have managed logging in and posting text to my wall. However, when I try posting the picture, nothing happens.
Where as I have debugged all that code and it is working properly and toast is also showing at the last but image is not uploaded on the wall.

This is my code to upload Image...

```
btnPostToWall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    facebook.authorize(AndroidFacebookConnectActivity.this, new String[]{ "user_photos,publish_checkins,publish_actions,publish_stream"},new DialogListener() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(Bundle values) {



       byte[] data = null;    
      Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
             ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
             bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);             
            data = baos.toByteArray();                
            Bundle params = new Bundle();              
            params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());              
            params.putString("method", "photos.upload");              
            params.putByteArray("picture", data);               
            AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);              
            mAsyncRunner.request("me/posts", params, "POST", new SampleUploadListener(), null);   
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Posted on Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
     }

     @Override
     public void onError(DialogError e)
     {
     }
     @Override
     public void onCancel() {
     }

    });

}

});
```

Comment: where is your image? on device or online

Comment: On device. Can you please suggest some solution......